# What does "Graduates from business school or Economics with mathematical background" mean?

Tags: logic

Hello I have a question about "English logic".

For instance on a job offer I see this requirement:

> Graduates from business school or economics with mathematical
> background.

So If I understand the sentence it means:

[image]

### However, how to say :

[image]

Being a non native English speaker I would say:

> Graduates **from** business school or **from** economics with mathematical background.

Am I right?

Moreover, is there any field who deals with that kind of question. If possible any fields who would use the kind of notation I'm using?

Comment: Yeah Sorry. By "U" I mean OR and by the inverse U symbol I mean AND.

Comment: It means whoever is writing this is not being clear. Most likely, they are just throwing out terms. Apply and see what they really want.

Comment: Hello Richard, thanks for your answer.  Actually I don't want to get the ad hoc job. I'm just interested to know if the English language has some special rule for that kind of "AND" "OR" condition...

Comment: I find your title question a bit of a riddle. Does "cond.1" mean *condition no.1* and "cond.a" *condition a* and so forth? If yes, is this a common way to contract the word, condition? Thank you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah you are right. No it's not a "common way". I just wrote cond. cuz it's too long to write condition many times on a title.

Comment: Can't you think of a way to rephrase your title? I think the question has potential and I bet a lot of users would at least read the rest of your question if the title was a *little* clearer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How would you recall it ? I don't really know how to recall it in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Well I'll try to do my best, you can always change things after my edit if I've got it wrong.

Comment: Lets see if people's interest is piqued by this title. I wish I could have done a better job.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I think is very good. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

The sentence is ambiguous, and could mean either of your two choices.

English is not math, and trying to write a sentence that conforms to the rules of mathematics or formal logic can often diminish clarity instead of enhancing it. Instead, it is better to write the sentence in whatever way will get your point across clearly, with a minimum of ambiguity.

I would write this in one of two ways, depending on what I wanted to say:

> Business or economics graduates with mathematical backgrounds...

or

> Business school graduates, or economics graduates with mathematical backgrounds...

Note that turning the noun phrases around (*X graduates*, rather than *graduates of X*) makes them easier to work with in this instance.

Comment: A man calls his wife, a programmer, at work and asks, "Honey, on the way home could you stop at the store and get a loaf of bread, and if they have eggs could you get a dozen?"  She brings 12 loaves of bread home.  As phenry says, "English is not math."  Now, in my little joke, who was "at work," the man or his wife?

Comment: I like this answer because it shows how using a comma can completely change the meaning of the sentence. "Business graduates or economics graduates with mathematical backgrounds" is not the same as "Business graduates, or economics graduates with mathematical backgrounds".